# How to chunk a big task(say it's 1gb file ) in javaScript using Timer and Interval?

Tags: javascript, java, asynchronous, timer, intervals

I am given a task to chunk a large text file(say 1gb file) into pieces using timers and intervals in javascript.It has to perform in an async way so that the code doesn't block.So for every 2 seconds,the part of the file(say 1mb) has to be read until all contents(1 GB) are read.How to do this ?

Comment: Can you use WebWorkers? It's made for stuff like this, but requires a newerish browser.

Comment: so you have to keep reading file asynchronously and divide it into chunks ? When a chunk is created do you need to pause the reading of file to be resumed after few seconds ?

Comment: @Sikorski Certainly Yes.Large file has to be read asynchronously(1mb,1mb) and once it is done,it should call a callback function.

Comment: @Matsemann Oh. .!Am new to that..!!Isn't it possible to done without webworkers as am completely unaware of that. .

Comment: @Matsemann could you share some link or some code that demonstrates about webworkers?

Comment: @AmudhaVigneshwaran is this supposed to be done at client side or server side(nodejs) ?

Comment: @Sikorski Forgot to mention .It's to be done on Client Side..